# Display black top and bottom load image from url

Tags: java, android

When i am loading image from url. Then ImageView is Displaying black color top and bottom in imageView. I am using glide library to load image. I have also used Picasso. But Issue not resolved.

**Screenshot**

Xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardView_elevation"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:id="@+id/video_thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:lines="2"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/video_thumbnail"
                    android:text="Happy Helloween Song | School hhe hel are ahowar eyou"
                    android:id="@+id/video_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/video_title"
                    android:id="@+id/video_publishTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:text="Morning ago : 12:9"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Java Code

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VideosViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Video video = mList.get(position);
        holder.mTitle.setText(video.getTitle());
        holder.mPublishTime.setText(video.getPublishAt());
        Glide.with(context).load(video.getThumbnail()).into(holder.mThumbnail)
  }
```

Comment: you passes fix dimension in width height of imageview. try to wrap_content and remove scaleType peroperty.

Comment: are you sure that original images do not have these black areas? your xml seems fine. Can you also share your code block where you use Glide?

Comment: yeah I am sure .

Comment: Hemant Parmar  i have also used wrap content dear

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :
Picasso.get()
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder) // set Default Image
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error) // set Default image
    .into(imageView);

Comment: Saurabh Bhardwaj the problem is not to set default image

Comment: But default image hold place Till then your image is not downloaded

Comment: Images are loading.